# Is it possible to have a wordpress installation with homepage and all pages on the root, but the posts on a subdir?

Tags: wordpress, customization

I want to use Wordpress as a CMS for pages and use the Posts for news or articles.

I'm planning to place the homepage and all other pages (about, contact, etc.) on the site root. I want only the posts on a different path (example: "/blog" ).

I didn't find any answers to help me use that specific structure.

Is that possible? How?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple trick to do it

First, login to your WordPress administration. Click “Settings” (or “Options”), then click “Permalinks.”

After the beginning slash in the “Custom Structure” box, add the subdirectory name followed by another slash.

For example, if your permalink structure was this:

```
/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/
```

…You would change it to this:

```
/blog/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%/%postname%/
```

Click the “Save Changes” button. Now your post and archive permalinks will contain the subdirectory name that you entered.

Comment: Thanks! 
I thought it was necessary to create a page and use some filters.
It is simpler than I thought.

Comment: Hi @rdweb glad to know you are happy with the solution :) Cheers :)